# Apache logging specific data

Tags: php, apache, logging, apache2, webserver

I'm trying to access Apache's access log and track bandwidth usage in real time.

As we know Apache logs every request made to the server, and the log file could be as big as couple of gigabytes so it would be pretty hard for PHP to phrase the log file.

Lets say I provide users with download links with **special URL prefix**.

Is there a way to only log those download links? if so I could use multi-log to log those data to another log file. [Multi Log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/multilogs.html)

Apache config uses `%u` to represent the URL, is there a way to filter this?

Answer (score 1):

Have php create the logfile, When people click on the link php could add to the log file and output what file to download.

```
<?php
    /*Logging Proccess*/
    $file = "Log.txt";
    $to_be_logged = file_get_contents($file);
    $to_be_logged .= /*Insert what you want to log like ip address or sumthing*/$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";
    file_put_contents($file, $to_be_logged);
    /*Download Script*/
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filetobedownloaded.rar");
?>
```

Put this in a file named download.php or something and
Add a file named Log.txt next to the file where this is located
This should work...

Comment: But you can't track bandwidth usage per file this way! Can you?

Comment: you could just make a log that inputs the size of each file and then add it all up when you need to see the total